# Running a script in a page when searching

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When i search something on my browser (Chrome) i want it to load a page and run a script.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('search_bar_input')[1].value = "%s"
document.getElementsByClassName('search')[0].click()
```

I have to fit everything in one, open the site, run the script, the script will then redirect me on another page.

I was looking for something like this

```
mywebsite.com javascript:{myscript}
```

but that doesn't work